# Magento 2 : Command bin/magento setup:upgrade failing after upgrade to 2.2.4?

Tags: magento2.2.4

I was upgrading Magento `2.2.3` to Magento `2.2.4`. Everything went ok but the final step is to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and when I run that I get the below error-

[image]

We can't save the address: Email has a wrong format.

Which email address has an issue? I have upgraded from `2.2.2 to 2.2.3` with no problem a few months ago.

Edit this is the new error-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but now its resolved after running the following query:

```
update sales_order_address a left join customer_entity b on a.customer_id = b.entity_id set a.email = b.email where a.email is null
```

I have found the answer https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14964

Comment: I was able to use the first one and it progressed. Once I did I got this error Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config at the Magento_Sales step

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. it is resolved after comment to single line code in below file.

vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Address/Validator.php

```
public function validate(Address $address)
{
    $warnings = [];
    foreach ($this->required as $code => $label) {
        if (!$address->hasData($code)) {
            $warnings[] = sprintf('%s is a required field', $label);
        }
    }
    if (!filter_var($address->getEmail(), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        //$warnings[] = 'Email has a wrong format';
    }
    if (!filter_var(in_array($address->getAddressType(), [Address::TYPE_BILLING, Address::TYPE_SHIPPING]))) {
        $warnings[] = 'Address type doesn\'t match required options';
    }
    return $warnings;
}
```

Note : remove this comment after once the set-upgrade process completed